# Need help making buttons red

Tags: html, button

hi I need to know how to change these to red without changing the look of them.
I have tried looking on other websites at there code and how they did it but most don't have buttons like this I have noticed and I unable to change the style as the owner of the website is picky so if anyone has any help please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Hmm are you trying to change the links to red? You don't have any buttons in that script. Also it may help to include a screenshot of the page with the buttons you wish to edit

Comment: yes that's the one! and I can do that. http://prntscr.com/a1q5vu

Comment: Can you please post the CSS code?

Comment: The style of these buttons is likely handled in a .css file in your website. Try to find that file and look for a block of code that references the banner div or the hrefs. You will have to edit that in order to change them to red. I don't really know much about CSS, but it looks to me like these buttons/links probably use an image. In which case I think you would have to change the image they reference

Comment: Please post your code (HTML and CSS), not images of code.

Comment: Please provide the essential HTML and CSS code within the question itself *as text* you may also provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you can change the color of the hyperlinks into a specific color by placing this in the body tag. Take note, this will change any hyperlink into red. Hope this is what you want to achieve.

```
<body link="red"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the color of a specific link, you can use style attribute as follows :

```
<a href="..." style="color:#CCAA00">my link</a>
```